# How often does 7 occur from number 1 to 1000?

Tags: permutations, combinations

How many times will the digit $7$ be written when listing the integers from $1$ to $1000$?

Is the following method correct?

For a single $7$,

$($C(1,1)$ \times$C(9,1)$\times$C(9,1)$)$$\times$3!

etc...

Comment: Answer it from 1 to 10; from 1 to 100.

Comment: Write numbers down to see how many 7s you will get

Answer (score 3):

Consider the number of times $7$ appears (a) as the units digit, (b) as the tens digit, (c) as the hundreds digit and add them together.